# Reposition jQuery Mobile popup after content change

Tags: jquery, mobile, resize, popup, positioning

I`m using jQuery Mobile (1.3.1) to display a popup (screen centered). Depending on the user actions, some content gets inserted into the popup via AJAX. This works fine, but there is one problem:
Once the content is injected into the popup its size changes, but the position is not updated.
As soon as the window is resized, the popup position gets refreshed, but so far I did not find a way to trigger this action manually.

Declaration of the popup:

```
<div id="MoveFolderPopup" data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" style="min-width: 20em">
```

Some things I already tried to reposition the popup to the window center (including a quick view to the popup widgets source code for some internal, undocumented events):

```
$('#MoveFolderPopup').trigger("reposition");
$('#MoveFolderPopup').trigger("_reposition");
$('#MoveFolderPopup').trigger("_handleWindowResize");
$('#MoveFolderPopup').trigger('refresh')
$(window).trigger('resize');
$('#MoveFolderPopup').popup('open');
$('#MoveFolderPopup').trigger('updatelayout');
```

I do not have many experiences with JavaScript and just don`t have any more ideas for this problem ;) Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$("#MoveFolderPopup").popup("reposition", {positionTo: 'origin'});
```

or

```
$("#MoveFolderPopup").popup("reposition", {positionTo: 'window'});
```

in this case either will do, because `data-position-to="window"`

Comment: Thank you, the second statement did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

This partially works for me:

```
$('#MoveFolderPopup').resize();
```

I did find that when triggering it immediately it didn't work well so I used `setTimeout`. It doesn't look very pretty though, I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while none of the provided solutions here worked in my case. The simple solution that solved my problem (and maybe also yours):

1. Close the popup
2. Add/replace content inside the popup
3. Open the popup (may be put in a timeout in case of closing takes a while)

This goes so quick that the user won't realise the popup was closed and opened again. The popup size is set based on the new content and not by previous content.

I have tested this also on mobile devices with Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

In case you have/want a **fullscreen popup** with changing contents you can put this code in the .ready section:

```js
// Position fullscreen popup
$("#yourPopupBoxId").popup({
    beforeposition: function () {
        $(this).css({
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            border: 'none',
            // Depending on content, otherwise ignore
            display: 'inline-table'
        });
    },
    x: 0,
    y: 0
});
```

With the provided solution you even don't need to programmatically scroll up to top in case of scrollable content. Closing and reopening the popup will always show you the start of the (scrollable) content.